# Having trouble displaying and saving with ng-options

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mean-stack, meanjs

My original error was that my select options weren't populating, I figured out that it was because angular couldn't see my scope because it was inside my "create" function. When I moved the scope object out of that function it populated my options, but when I selected an option they disappeared....
This was because my select was tied into an ng-model that didnt have access to that scope. If I change the model, when I save it to the database it saves it as [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]
Which is not what I want.

I am confused because, doesn't my select need to be tied to the correct model in order to save to the right attribute in the database?
How does a model see a scope when you aren't supposed to manipulate date in the model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

MODEL

```js
var StrainSchema = new Schema({
 name: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  required: 'Please specify a Strain name',
  trim: true
 },
 description: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  required: 'Describe the Strain',
  trim: true
 },
 stype: {
  type: String,
  default: '',
  required: 'Specify type of Strain',
  trim: true
 },
 created: {
  type: Date,
  default: Date.now
 },
 user: {
  type: Schema.ObjectId,
  ref: 'User'
 }
});
```

CONTROLLER

```js
$scope.stype = [
    {id: '1', name: 'Indica'},
    {id: '2', name: 'Sativa'},
    {id: '3', name: 'Hybrid'}
   ];

  // Create new Strain
  $scope.create = function() {
   
   
   // Create new Strain object
   var strain = new Strains ({
    name: this.name,
    description: this.description,
    stype: this.stype
   });
   
   

   // Redirect after save
   strain.$save(function(response) {
    $location.path('strains/' + response._id);

    // Clear form fields
    $scope.name = '';
    $scope.description = '';
    $scope.stype = '';
   }, function(errorResponse) {
    $scope.error = errorResponse.data.message;
   });
  };
```

HTML / VIEW

```js
 <label class="control-label" for="stype">Type</label>
                    <div class="controls">
                        <select name="stype" id="stype" class="form-control" data-ng-model="stype" data-ng-options="type.name for type in stype">
                            <option value="">-- Choose Type --</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Maybe it's because you're using the same variable name (stype) either on "ng-model" and "ng-options". Once you select an option, "stype" becomes an string, not an array anymore. Try to use different names for model and your array of stype (stypes, for example).

Comment: That was the problem, thank you!
Now I'm getting a new error.... I am getting "Specify type of Strain", it looks like it isn't passing the required parameter in my  model. 

Any idea why?

Comment: can you make a plunker please ?

Comment: @macrog http://plnkr.co/wFWUAfX93PFkDdlw3Z1Y

Comment: @macrog I don't think it works, but thats my code

Comment: With the code you provided, we can't clearly see the problem. Check if your mongoose module and schema are ok.

Comment: @nersoh I keep getting "angular is not defined" on plunker. Not sure why.

But basically, the data isnt being recognized in my options as being selected, so it isnt passing my 'required' parameter in my model above... so its giving me the error of "Specify type of Strain". Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing [link] http://i58.tinypic.com/1549d28.png [/link]

Comment: I've learned that it is saving nothing (blank) to the database, when I disabled required in my model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I wasnt specifying the correct string for the value attribute.

```html
data-ng-options="type.name as type.name for type in stypes"
```

The first type.name puts my "name" string into the value attribute, the value is what is being saved to the database, not the text in the option.